# What happened to the library called 'stockPortfolio'?

Tags: r

I am trying to use this library: 'stockPortfolio'

After several attempts, I just couldn't get it to install.  I just found this.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stockPortfolio/index.html

Is it gone because Yahoo shut off it's finance API last year?  Is that the bottom line here?  I'm getting an error about 'Error in library(stockPortfolio) : 
  there is no package called ‘stockPortfolio’'.  I'm asking, because I am trying to run the code from the link below:

http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio/r-code-graph-efficient-frontier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to email the maintainer to ask.

If you still want to use the last version of the package (no idea if a script using it will work, probably not if the API shut down), you can do `remotes::install_version("stockPortfolio", version = "1.2")`.

Comment: Upvoted. It's too bad installing this way doesn't show up in the Packages window in R Studio. p.s. Do you know if the stocks package is similar to the stockPortfolio package?

Comment: Unfortunately, because that package is so old, the endpoints don't match anymore. So while the functions like `getReturns` execute, the data won't load. `cannot open the connection to 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=0&b=1&c=1970&g=w&ignore=.csv'`